# Google and One Drive Folders

Tags: php, google-drive-api, onedrive

Just as a side project I want to be able to do an online file storage system. Thinking about some of the details and plans I want, I thought of the Google and One Drive Folders.

My question is how do they get folders on your pc that you can use to upload? Its seems like mapping a network drive but to a server or something.

I don't want an API necessarily. I would love to know how they do it and if could get pointed in the right direction as how to do this myself.

Thanks!

---

What I realized after posting this, is that there must be a program that kind of runs in the background. When a new file is recognized in the folder, it FTP the new files to the server.

Am I on the right track?

Also I forgot to post the screenshot of the folders I am talking about. Sorry!

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Both services have API documentations explaining how to use the features. Just in case you were thinking to use either on your site for some sort of file sharing thing: prepare for a loadful of headaches.

Comment: I was just curious how I would be able do duplicate how they make the folders on my computer and how the files get uploaded.

Comment: I don't really want to use an API, I could figure out how to do something similar myself. I am just curious how they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these services have a couple of fundimental features

1. the ability to upload and download content on a remote file system
2. a method to determine what changes have been made on that remote file system
3. a method to determine what changes have been made on the local file system
4. a method to manage synchronising changes between the remote and local file systems

For the OneDrive service, there is an [API](http://dev.onedrive.com) which enables programs to upload and download content #1, it also has a [delta](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/view_delta.htm) API that makes #2 straight forward.

Then for the OneDrive desktop client, it has filesystem watchers that get notified whenever files on the local system change for #3.  Then finally this OneDrive desktop client has logic to determine the priority of changes and how to manage conflicts between the file system and the remote file store #4.

Comment: That is what I kinda thought in a general sense, but this is what I was looking for to know exactly so I could understand it more. Thank you!